# Is there a way to execute a query with placeholders without preparing the function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, security, activerecord, pgbouncer

My codebase has a potential vulnerability of SQL injection that I'd like to secure. I have a few queries in my codebase where I put variables in plain text, like this:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
        %{
          SELECT ...
          FROM ...
          JOIN ...
          WHERE ...
           ... model.foreign_id IN (#{array_of_ids})
          GROUP BY 1;
        }
      )
```

I'm doing it like this because I don't think it's possible to use built-in ActiveRecord queries, due to the complexity of the query (there are ones more complex that we'd like to control).

My first thought was to use exec_query, but I've found I can't use that. I am using pgbouncer in transaction mode, so prepared_statements must remain off. Is there a way to execute a query with placeholders without preparing the function?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the ActiveRecord sanitize methods

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql(['? IN ?', 'foreign_key', [1, ';true=true']])

=> "'model_name.foreign_key' IN 1,';true=true'"
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blame/8642c564dab37366c2ca8950b428d1aec84eb10d/activerecord/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb
https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9d43a84f73c1b3853a91d052a462ee60eccaf957